# Should an open source library with a blocking method offer an asynchronous option for execution?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, open-source, processbuilder

**Background:**

I am creating library that I want to make open source.
This library is designed for use in backend processes.
The service I will make available utilizes Java's `ProcessBuilder`, to execute several native commands.
This service will often finish processing commands in under 1 second, but in rare cases, may take several minutes.

**Questions:**

In a situation where a public library has methods that may become blocking, should the library provide an async option for calling that method? Or should such a library remain unopinionated, and leave that to the users to implement?

Here are a couple ways of how I have been thinking of implementing this service...

**Example 1: unopinionated**

- `SomeService`, with blocking method
- if user wants to run asynchronously, they must figure it out

SomeService.java

```
public class SomeService {
    public Response process(Request request) {
        //do stuff for 60 seconds
    }
}
```

**Example 2: opinionated**

- `SomeService`, with blocking method
- optional `SomeProcessTask`, which users can utilize to bypass blocking method and run async.

SomeProcessTask.java

```
public class SomeProcessTask implements Callable<Response> {
    private final Request request;

    public SomeProcessTask(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public Response call(Request request) {
        //do stuff for 60 seconds
    }
}
```

SomeService.java

```
public class SomeService {
    public Response process(Request request) {
        SomeProcessTask task = new SomeProcessTask(request);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Response> future = executor.submit(task);
        return future.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Future#get` blocks. So you’ve not really accomplished your goal of being async.

Comment: How would you properly shutdown the executor service? If the app were to end before shutting down your executor, the thread backing your executor service could continue running indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️.

Comment: Concurrency is tricky. Perhaps it would be best to keep your library simple. Let the calling programmer deal with concurrency if they deem it important.

Comment: @BasilBourque If I call executor.shutdown(), it will close everything, right? Thats the plan - I'm just trying to provide a simplified example without a bunch of noise, so we can cut to the chase and answer my bigger question.

Comment: @BasilBourque YES, that's the kind of answer I looking for. I feel the same way. And I am not very experienced with concurrency, and it kind of feels like I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: No, calling `shutdown` is insufficient. See the boilerplate given to you on the Javadoc for `ExecutorService`. And see the default implementation of `ExecutorService#close`.

Comment: You absolutely should _not_ create a new `ExecutorService` in every call to `process`. That completly defeats the purpose using a thread pool. Create one, static instance, and re-use it. Better still, provide the client with the ability to _inject_ their own `ExecutorService`, and only create yours if they choose not to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You commented:

> I am not very experienced with concurrency

Then you most definitely should *not* attempt making your library run concurrently. **Concurrency is tricky.** An example is the code seen in the Question; multiple concurrency problems have been identified in the Comments.

Keep your library simple.  **Focus on its core purpose.** Let the calling programmer deal with concurrency if they deem it important.

You should **document for the calling programmer** any aspects of your library that may impact its use concurrently. Most especially, mention any issue that would contraindicate its use with [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444). Such issues include:

- Calling out to **native code**.
- Running long-executing work within **`synchronized` blocks**. (Or else re-implement those with `ReentrantLock`.)
- Being **CPU-bound** for long-executing work. For example, video-encoding without any blocking calls like logging, file I/O, database interaction, or network access.

---

To learn more about concurrency, read the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz et al. And study the [Java Memory Model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model).

To learn about virtual threads, see talks by Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, or José Paumard.

Comment: Will do - thank you for the quick feedback my friend!